# Angular, order of $formatters and $parsers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an existing 3rd party directive for which I need to modify model and view values before they are shown resp. saved to the model. As I would like to avoid modifying external code, I implemented an additional directive which is set via attribute and which is about to modify the data through the `$formatters` and `$parsers` pipeline.

Basically something like this:

```
app.directive('myModifyingDirective', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
                return 'modified_' + modelValue;
            });
            // similar for $parsers
        }
    };
});
```

Markup looks something like:

```
<third-party-directive my-modifying-directive ng-model='data'></third-party-directive>`
```

The problem is, that `third-party-directive` also contributes to the `$formatters`, and at the end, the `third-party-directives`'s formatter is last entry in the `$formatters` array, and thus executed before `my-modifying-directive`.

However, I require `my-modifying-directive` to be executed first.

Is there any mechanism how I could influence the order of the `$parsers`?

Comment: Have you tried setting a higher/lower priority on your directive?

Comment: Have you tried`ngModelController.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
                return 'modified_' + modelValue;
            });` ? This would add your formatter to the front of the array.

Comment: @SunilD. Wow, never heard of an explicit priority before, but that did the trick!!! Thank you, feel free to post that as an answer!

Comment: @aperl Yes, but adding to the front would mean it would get executed as last formatter, as they are executed in reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [priority](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-) of the directive so that it is higher or lower than the priority of the 3rd party directive:

> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.